# Honda Odessy 03 Shift Lock

Tags: shifting

So me and my Dad are Replacing a transmission for a Honda Odessy 2003 and When we tried to start the car we couldnt cause the shift gear is stuck on Drive what do i do about this?

Comment: Please proofread your question and edit it so that it's clear about what you are asking.  But I think you're saying it's stuck in D.  I'd check the shift linkage first to make sure it's correctly connected.

Comment: Sounds like you did something wrong when replacing the transmission, check the shift cable, disconnect it from the trans, will it go into park now?